# Whitespace in argument of javascript / jQuery "insertAfter" function causes failure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to insert some html after a button, when that button is clicked is clicked

The following function works well:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('#someid').click(function() {     
        $('<div>Hello world</div>').insertAfter($('#someid').parent());                
     });
});
```

I've discovered two things I don't undestand:

1.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){        
        $('#someid').click(function() {     
            $('<div>Hello world</div>
               <div>another div</div>    <p>some html</p>


               <div>weird spacing</div>
              ').insertAfter($('#someid').parent());                
         });
    });
```

Does not work, i.e the introduction of whitespace between elements (or line breaks?) causes the function to fail.

2.

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('#someid').click(function() {     
        $('Im just a string not good HTML').insertAfter($('#someid').parent());                
     });
});
```

Also fails, it seems if I don't insert valid HTML as the argument of the function, it doesn't insert it?

2) is just a curiosity but 1)is stopping me pasting in a large chunk of HTML that I want to be the inserted HTML if button is clicked, do I have to remove all the whitespace?

Comment: 2) is probably because you have an apostrophe. Escape it with `$('I\'m just a string')`

Comment: use your browser console to check for errors, both samples will throw errors in console, and point to the problem line. WHen in doubt, paste code into online linter like jshint.com

Comment: @charlietfl ah yes, I was using my console and it was pointing me to the line that caused it, but I wanted to know why it caused it - didn't know that line breaks = expression termination in js

Comment: @GluePear ah - actually in the example I was practicing with I used a string with no apostrophe, although what you say is true. See this jsfiddle for my confusion: http://jsfiddle.net/4wy4s/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because of the escape uses of escape characters.

Line breaks are treated as end of statement in javascript, you can use a `\` at the end to escape it in a string literal

```
   $(document).ready(function(){        
        $('#someid').click(function() {     
            $('<div>Hello world</div>\
               <div>another div</div>    <p>some html</p>\
               \
               \
               <div>weird spacing</div>\
              ').insertAfter($('#someid').parent());                
         });
    });
```

Also since you have used `'` enclose the string any instance of it within the string also has to be escaped with `\`

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('#someid').click(function() {     
        $('I\'m just a string not good HTML').insertAfter($('#someid').parent());                
     });
});
```

Comment: Ah ha! thank you, I understand. But the second one isn't so, I actually tested using 'hello', it was silly of me to use an apostrophe in my example. see this jsfiddle for an example of my confusion:
http://jsfiddle.net/4wy4s/1/

Comment: @Gideon jQuery treats `bad html` as a selector... it looks for an `html` element inside a `bad` element like `<bad>...<html>asdf</html>..</bad>`